# How to load an external html and it´s css files with XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to load an html and it`s css files into other html with XMLHttpRequest()
The problem is that the html file is loaded but not it´s css file.

it is possible to load the file so that it looks the same as the original?

I have achieved this by loading it into a full screen iframe but would like to achieve this without the use of an iframe.

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {   // XMLHttpRequest.DONE == 4
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
};

xmlhttp.open("GET", "myHtmlWithCss.html", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: Request the CSS file too and inject the response into the page? Xmlhttp doesn't automatically pull all the resources required by the html file

Comment: Ok. Do you know any way to get it?

Answer (score 0):

Try next

```
<object type="text/html" data="your-file.html" width="100%" height="100%" />
```

Maybe you need to assign "height: 100vh;" with extra css.